# google maps API v3 in an iFrame doesnt work - issue in IE

Tags: google-maps, iframe, google-maps-api-3, internet-explorer-8

I have a CMS website (hosted on the A server) and would like to place a Google Map on one of the pages there.

What I did was to create a new html page (hosted on B server) that does the mapping and adds few markers using Google API v3.

Our CMS is something like Wikipedia (we can edit pages) so I thought of adding an iframe (on a page from A server) to the new html page that I created (located on B server).
Everything loads perfectly in IE, Chrome, FF I can see the map loading in the iFrame with  10-20 markers on the map.

Here is the problem: in IE8 the map is frozen, i cannot use the mouse to navigate throughout the map. I can still get the infowindows to load but the map is not moving when I drag it.

Few more details:

- IF I put the same iFrame on a different host (different from the CMS machine), it would all work with no problem - but obviously we need this to show in the CMS.
- IF I switch the compatibility mode on my IE8, it would start working: it would enable me using the mouse and move/drag the map.
- IF I point the iFrame to pages on the web that are delivered through SSL, it would work fine .
- IF the mapping is done on v2 (as opposed to v3) - it also seems like it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Without a url to test with, we're left to make guesses.

Here's a couple:

- Since you mentioned SSL, make sure you are loading the Maps API via SSL and that your problem isn't currently being caused by non-SSL content. The IE developer tools should have warnings on the console if this is the case.
- Use the IE specific [X-UA-Compatible header/meta tag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325.aspx) inside your iframe to specify compatibility mode.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it works in IE but you need to set width and height.
By default IE doesn't accept width:100% and height:100% and you have to do something like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
html
{
    height:100%;
}
body
{
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#google_map
{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    height:inherit;
    width:inherit;
}
</style>
```

And Google map is in a div by id="google_map".

```
<div id="google_map"></div>
```